# String.Split in .Net FW - why no overload that takes a single string?

Tags: .net

...e.g. String.Split(Delim As String).

Comment: I don't expect a definitive answer, of course - it's just one of those things that seems a bit odd - it's far too easy to try e.g. mystring.Split(" ") only to be scolded by the compiler.

Comment: It does have an overload which takes a single character.

Comment: Not according to the docs http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx - is this undocumented?

Comment: No - it's params :-) Therefore, when writing e.g. s.Split(';') you are actually calling the overloading accepting a char-array which the compiler generates for you.

Comment: Ah - I see, thanks for the heads-up!  That explains why my call worked when I tested this and yet .Net Reflector didn't show up any String.Splits that looked viable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is odd, have cursed at it myself several times.  Equally odd is that the Split() overloads that take a string were not available in .NET 1.x.  Well, odder perhaps.  Maybe some "not too many overloads!" paralysis here.  The StringSplitOptions and Count arguments can generate a combinatorial number of them.

Fix it with an extension method:

```
public static class Extensions {
    public static string[] Split(this string s, string separator) {
        return s.Split(new string[] { separator }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    }
}
```

And add the ones you need if you also want to cover StringSplitOptions and Count :)

Comment: Too many overloads sounds like a reasonable guess at a reason to me, thanks Hans - the extension method 'workaround' is a good one - at least 'til .Net 7.0 is released which supports 1,437 different overloads of String.Split.